# Does $\text{POS($X$)}=\text{CH(POS($X$))}$ hold?

Tags: solution-verification, convex-optimization

Does the following relation hold?

$$\text{POS($X$)}=\text{CH(POS($X$))}$$
Where $\text{CH($X$)}$ is the set of all convex combinations of points in $X$ and $\text{POS($X$)}$ is the set of all non-negative combinations of points in $X$, and $ \emptyset\ne X \subset \mathbb R^n$.

I've proved the result, just want to know the validity of it.

---

**Lemma 1**:$\text{POS($X$)}$ is convex.

Let $a,b$ be arbitrary elements in $\text{POS($X$)}$ and $\lambda \in (0,1)$, then based on the definition of $\text{POS($X$)}$: $$\exists \lambda_1,...,\lambda_n\ge0:a=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\lambda_j x_j$$
$$\exists \lambda_1',...,\lambda_m'\ge0:b=\sum_{j=1}^{m}\lambda_j' x_j$$

Let $\forall j \in \{\text{min}\{m,n\}+1,...,\text{max}\{m,n\}\}:\lambda_j=0$,then:
$$\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b =\sum_{j=1}^{\text{max}\{m,n\}}\underbrace{(\lambda \lambda_j+(1-\lambda)\lambda_j')}_{\ge 0}x_j \in \text{POS($X$)}$$

---

**Lemma 2**: $Y$ is convex iff $\text{CH}(Y)=Y$

Proof:

$\Rightarrow$

Regardless of $Y$ being convex or not, for any $a \in Y$ $$1a  \in \text{CH}(Y)$$
So $\text{CH}(Y) \supseteq Y$.

On the other hand $\text{CH}(Y) $ is the smallest convex set containing $Y$,Which means that $$\text{CH}(Y)=\bigcap_{\;\;\;Y \subseteq F \\F  \text{  convex} }F$$

Now convexity of $Y$ shows that $$\text{CH}(Y)=\bigcap_{\;\;\;Y \subset F \\F  \text{  convex} }F  \cap Y$$

So for some $a \in \text{CH}(Y) \implies a \in Y$,So $\text{CH}(Y) \subseteq Y$.

Finally we see that $\text{CH}(Y)=Y$.

$\Leftarrow$

We know that $\text{CH}(Y)$ is  convex set, and since $\text{CH}(Y)=Y$, so $Y$ is also convex.

---

Now from **Lemma 1**, we know that $\text{POS($X$)}$ is convex
, and from **Lemma 2** $$\text{POS($X$)}=\text{CH(POS($X$))}$$

Comment: No, the two sides are equal. Basically, $\operatorname{POS}(X)$ is convex.  $\operatorname {CH}(Y)=Y$ iff $Y$ is convex.

Comment: seems that POS(X) is a (pointed) convex cone.